# How to create soapvar object for xsd:anyType

Tags: php, soap

Can anyone please explain how to assign the type for anytype paramater using soapvar in php?

```
  <complexType name="Entry">
            <sequence>
                <element name="key" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="value" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType" minOccurs="0" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
```

For example:

```
$arr=array('key'=>new SoapVar('EMAIL_ADDRESS',SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'xsd:anyType'),'value'=>new SoapVar('xxxx@gmail.com',SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'xsd:anyType'));
```

When passing the above array for userprofile in register user along soapclient in yodlee sdk it return "Unknown" exception.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the above code (missing quote at the end) - could this be anything to do with the problem, or is it just a copy/paste error in creating the question?

Comment: Thanks Dave i corrected above questions please check now and reply your thoughts

Answer (score 6):

Hai i finally found out my issue its based on namespace url problem and i used this

```
$arr=array('key'=>new SoapVar('EMAIL_ADDRESS',XSD_ANYTYPE,'string','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','key'),'value'=>new SoapVar('xxxx@gmail.com',XSD_ANYTYPE,'string','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','value'));
```

and got solution from yodlee server thanks to all